# Assigning an object to static variable

Tags: php, oop, singleton

What i'm Doing Wrong

```
class db
{

     static $dbintance=null;    


     public function __construct()
     {


       try
       {
       self::$dbintance=new PDO("mysql:host=host;dbname=dbname",user,password);
       }
       catch( PDOException $e)
       {
       die( '<b>Errors:</b> '.$e->getMessage());
       }

       }


     public static function isRecord($q)
       {

    $r=self::$dbintance->query($q)->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM);
    if($r[0]) return true; 
    if(!$r[0]) return false;
   }  

}
```

Usage

```
 echo (db::isRecord("SELECT * FROM whcentral1 WHERE ItemDesc='ff'"))?'Yes':'NO';
```

Error

Call to a member function query() on a non-object

Comment: "What i'm Doing Wrong" you are using a singleton, that's what you're doing wrong.

Comment: Is that bad to use `singleton` ?

Comment: it is bad exactly because of the problem you face. If it was a normal object, it will not be possible to call a method, without creating it first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP doesn't do static constructors.  The way you've written this, you'd actually have to run `new db()` before it would work.  You might be better off using a static accessor method, e.g.:

```
class db {

 static $dbintance=null;    


 public static function getConnection(){
   if (!self::$dbinstance) {
     try {
         self::$dbintance=new PDO("mysql:host=host;dbname=dbname",user,password);
     } catch( PDOException $e) {
         die( '<b>Errors:</b> '.$e->getMessage());
     }

  }
  return self::$dbinstance;
// etc.
}
```

Comment: It didn't work because you were initializing the PDO object in the class constructor.  The problem is that constructors in PHP are only run for class instances and you were calling a static method.  So unless you create an instance of the class somewhere along the line, the constructor would not be run and so the PDO object would not be set.

Comment: Prefer use of static over self.In this case it doesn't affect still if you are doing static method overriding,It may bite you.http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.late-static-bindings.php